# Would you tell me what I am?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I am frequently prone to distraction,
>   But often I am making the big decision.
>   Many a tunnel has been me,
>   And I have been many a tree.
>
> Sometimes I can be rolling fast,
>   Other how a Baratheon passed.
>   As the game goes on I stayed the same,
>   Bearing whatever weights had came.

What am I?

Comment: Is S.O.A.B. intended?

Comment: I BM a SOAB. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My answer is

> bored/board

I am frequently prone to distraction,

> When bored, you are prone to distraction.

But often I am making the big decision.

> A board is a group of people constituted as the decision-making body of an organisation.

Many a tunnel has been me,

> To bore is to make a hole in something so many man-made tunnels are bored.

And I have been many a tree.

> A board can refer to a long, thin, flat piece of wood.

Sometimes I can be rolling fast,

> A skate board rolls fast

Other how a Baratheon passed.

> Robert Baratheon was bored by a boar.

As the game goes on I stayed the same,

> A board game is a game that involves moving counters around a board.

Bearing whatever weights had came.

> The past tense of bear is bore, so you bored the weights.

Comment: Well my weakest hint was definitely the bearing whatever weights line, which I meant to refer to the fact that boards often are used in structures. And the Baratheon thing was aiming for a pun on boared, but also that (puns are fun). Good job.